# current date not changing the format after using dateformatter

Tags: ios, nsdate

I need help with this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];

NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

NSString* myString = [df stringFromDate:now];
NSDate *date1=[[NSDate alloc]init];
NSDate *date2=[[NSDate alloc]init];

date1 = [df dateFromString:myString];
```

In this I print the date I got like this after dateformatter `2013-12-06 18:30:00 +0000`

```
date2 = [df dateFromString:purchase_date];
```

Comment: Which is exactly what you should get when you NSLog an NSDate object.  Please look at any of the several thousand other questions like this.

Comment: And, by the way, DO NOT "initialize" an object pointer that you're about to set a new value into.  It's wastes CPU and heap and annoys code reviewers.

Comment: please tell, in that what is wrong in my code

Comment: You failed to read any documentation on NSDate. "To parse strings containing dates and to generate string representations of a date, you should use an instance of NSDateFormatter using the methods dateFromString: and stringFromDate: respectively—see “Date Formatters” for more details."

Comment: at mystring nslog i am getting the value in  dateformatter style again i convert that mystring into date it is changing the formatt that's my problem@Hot Licks

Comment: Read that again.  To generate a string representation use NSDateFormatter.

Comment: @HotLicks It doesn't annoy all code reviewers. For some of us it reminds us where we started. Please stick to the facts.

Comment: YOU CANNOT CHANGE THE "FORMAT" OF AN NSDate OBJECT!  You can only format the NSDate into the string format of your choice.